# Why isn't $\mathscr A^{\uparrow} \subset \mathscr A$?

Tags: measure-theory

Assume $\Omega$ is a set, $P(\Omega)$ the power set of $\Omega$ and $\mathscr A$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. Furthermore, let $\mathscr A^{\uparrow}$ be the set of all sets $A \in P(\Omega)$ such that $A$ can be written as a union of a countable family of elements of $\mathscr A$.

Now, my book claims that "trivially", the relation

$\mathscr A \subset \mathscr A^{\uparrow}$

holds. What I don't understand is: Why isn't actually $\mathscr A^{\uparrow} \subset \mathscr A$? I mean, following the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, every union of a (countable) family of elements of $\mathscr A$ must be a part of $\mathscr A$ too. So why is this not the case here? I can't think of a set that can be written like that without being a part of $\mathscr A$.

Comment: If $\mathscr{A}$ is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathscr{A}^{\uparrow} = \mathscr{A}$. Was perhaps $\mathscr{A}$ only assumed to be an algebra of sets rather than a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Yes, indeed. :D Sorry, sometimes one misses miss the wood for the trees.